# OpenCV highgui module can't be built in Mac with GCC

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv, gcc

I am trying to compile OpenCV 2.4.9 from source in Mac OS X 10.9.4 with GCC 4.8.2 (installed by brew) but I can't build the highgui module at all.

By default, it tries to use the Cocoa framework with headers that seem to be Objective C 2 and that can't be parsed by GCC. I get these errors:

```
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_cocoa.mm.o
opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_cocoa.mm: In function 'void cvDestroyAllWindows()':
opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_cocoa.mm:200:23: error: expected ';' before 'in'
     for(NSString *key in list) {
```

I tried using Qt 4.8.6 (installed by brew) and activating `WITH_QT` in cmake. I think I ran into the same problem as above. I get this:

```
[ 27%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_qtkit.mm.o
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Headers/QTKit.h:51:0,
                 from opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/cap_qtkit.mm:46:
/System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Headers/QTMovieModernizer.h:123:46: error: expected ')' before '(' token
 - (void)modernizeWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))handler AVAILABLE_QTKIT_VERSION_7_7_3_AND_LATER;
                                              ^
```

Finally, I tried with Carbon by activating `WITH_CARBON`, which should be available in Mac. I get several errors like this:

```
opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_carbon.cpp: In function 'void icvDrawImage(CvWindow*)':
opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_carbon.cpp:227:54: error: 'GetWindowPortBounds' was not declared in this scope
         GetWindowPortBounds(window->window, &portrect);
                                                      ^
```

Any way to build highgui without falling back to Clang?

Comment: Have you tried submitting a bug report with OpenCV?

Comment: I've got the same error trying to build wxWidgets on Mac with g++ 4.9. :-/